# Is this truth table possbile

Tags: circuits, digital-circuits

[image]

I am trying to figure out if this truth table is possible. I've tried inverting the numbers, adding them, subtracting them, but I still cant find anything that works. I am starting to think that this is not possible.

Comment: There are 16 distinct truth tables. All are expressible in terms of AND or OR and NOTs.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `A AND (NOT B)`?